# How to run a single shoulda context test in ruby Test::Unit framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, shoulda

I can typically test a regular Test::Unit method using the following commandline syntax for a method "delete_user_test":

```
ruby functional/user_controller_test.rb -n delete_user_test
```

Now when I'm using the shoulda plugin with Test::Unit I try to use the same technique as follows:

```
... 
context "Deleting a User" do
  should "remove user from user table" do
    ...
  end
end
```

Then I try to run the single test as follows:

```
ruby functional/user_controller_test.rb -n "test: Deleting a User should remove user from user table"
```

This doesn't work.  Does anyone know how I can run a single context tests using shoulda and Test::Unit.  I have a couple of different test in one test file and I want to only run the one using TDD without having to wait for all tests to run.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ruby functional/user_controller_test.rb -n "/Deleting a User/"
```

Just put some reasonably long string from your context name into the regular expression.

Comment: Interestingly, using "/Deleting_a_User/" would work before using shoulda, but now you can, and actually have to, use "/Deleting a User/"

Answer (score 6):

Using the full name of the test with a space at the end seems to work too:

```
ruby -Itest 
     functional/user_controller_test.rb 
     -n "test: Deleting a user should remove user from user table. "
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining the two approaches has worked well for me; using both `-I test` and the regexp.

```
ruby -Itest functional/user_controller_teset.rb -n "/remove user from user table/"
```